# Strategy for determining the closed form of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recursion

Is there a strategy that I should be implementing when trying to find the closed-form of sequences? Right now, I'm relying a fair bit of pattern-recognition (i.e. it's a crapshoot), which isn't turning out to be very efficient. Here's one I'm working on currently:

[image]

What's the best way to approach these?

Comment: $\left(\frac{(-1)^n(n+1)}{3^n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$

Comment: So you accomplished in two minutes what took me over an hour of trial and error. Would you mind explaining the steps you took?

Comment: The denominator is $3^n$. The signe of the numerator is $-,+,-,+,\ldots$; so it's $(-1)^{n+1}$. If you forget the sign of the numerator, what remains is $2,3,4,\ldots$

Comment: There can be **no general method** for such problems. As you wrote "it's a crapshoot". The first reason is that "closed form" only applies to a limited number of sequences. Almost all sequences have no closed form. The second reason is that knowing only the frst few terms does not uniquely determine a sequence. You may find the sequence in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org) and the entry may provide a closed form.

Comment: Appreciate the answers.